# Spring MongoDB sorting overflow

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

There are 300 records in my mongoDB, and I do the querying with the following code :

```
Criteria c = ...;
Query q = new Query(c).limit(10).skip(skip);
q = q.with(new Sort(Sort.DEFAULT_DIRECTION.DESC,"fromDate"));
List<Event> results = mongoTemplate.find(q, Event.class, "Event");
```

When skip = 40, this code works fine.

However, when skip = 260, I get the following error:

**Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33564943 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes;**

It seems that mongoDB has overflow problem when sorting with large amount of records. Can anyone suggest how to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongodb has a 32mb limit on in memory sort:  Details here:

[mongo sort limit](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Sorted-Documents)

You should be indexing your sort field, and this will fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Can we set annotate multiple fields with @Indexed? Because depending on the user request, we need to do the sorting by different fields.  (Sometimes we need to sort by Date....while in the other case, we need to sort by title...etc).

Comment: Yes, I believe this is what you are looking for.  https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-compound-index/  (unless you just need to create multiple single indexes which is perfectly fine to do)